# Connection between 2 C# applications

Tags: c#, connection, client

I'd like to make server-client game in which both sides are made in C#. How can i make connection between those applications? What is the most efficient way?
Every 60ms i will send from client data what action did player, his session-id, and maybe some additional data like message. Client will send data about sheet of map, success of players action. 
Second question: what's name of algorithm that when player is logging in, he uses password, but then client will generate randomly unique session id and both sides will use it instead of players password?

Comment: Have you considered WebService?

Comment: I suggest you to use Socket (System.Net.Socket) to communicate between 2 apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use TcpListener and TcpClient classes. Here is a basic example: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/304417/Problem-implementing-Csharp-Client-Server-to-keep

Answer (score 0):

I would use WCF, then you are able to use a variety of clients. You can use remoting for windows client,s and posisbly build a web-interface in addition

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like WCF would be the answer if you are using C#.  The WCF Service that you create for the server can utilise the built in Sessions which can give you a Session Id.

I would suggest using the NetTcp Bindings for it as it is faster than any of the Http bindings.  You can easily change or add more bindings the config file at a later date to support more types.  That way, your game will be easily extensible - you could even expose the server web service to allow people to develop their own clients.